# How to get checked checkbox value of specified div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```
<td id="optrep0">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="warna" id="warna" name="warna[]"> 
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" class="warna" id="warna" name="warna[]">
  </td>
<td id="optrep1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="warna" id="warna" name="warna[]"> 
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" class="warna" id="warna" name="warna[]">
  </td>
<td id="optrep2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="warna" id="warna" name="warna[]"> 
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" class="warna" id="warna" name="warna[]">
  </td>
```

I need to find checked value of specified `div`s having `id`s: `optrep0`,`optrep1`,`optrep2` above, I have tried using

```
var optrep0= jQuery(':checkbox:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

And send `optrep0` variable to server, but it will send every checked value. So, I want to send only specified `div`s only per variable, I also tried

```
 var optrep0= jQuery('#optrep0>#warna:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
     return this.value;
 }).get();
```

PS: sub id name on td id cannot be changed as is as, I only need javascript example how to solve this case, thank you :D

Comment: Why you have same `id`?

Comment: Yes. because server fixed send same id for the selector, I cannot change the name thought, but I can only create parent id to make the option unique

Comment: So generate a different id, for example: `warna1`, `warna2`, or use `timestamp`. :)

Comment: As I said before, sub id name "warna" cannot change, it should be used as is as due server issue, just need to find how to solve this case

Comment: Yeah, name cannot be changed, but if input is generated into a loop, it's easy to do it, or use javascript to do this! ;)

Comment: Hard to tell you, the code is quite complex, that list is generated from ajax request. Thank you for the tips

Comment: Ah ok, and you need to browse through all element, then, you can incremente a value to do it!

You're welcome! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give space in `>`  and use `dot` for class `warna`

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5yadu1gu/)

```
var optrep0= jQuery('#optrep0 > .warna:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: thank you for quick answer, finally I can move on :D
again thankyou Mr.Adil

Answer (score 3):

Try using descendant selector by putting a `>` and don't use `:checkbox`, only `:checked` is needed

```
var optrep0= jQuery('#optrep0 > :checked').map(function () {
 return this.value;
 }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the preferable way is

```
var optrep0= jQuery('#optrep0 > .warna:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bct2fngs/)